# Can you freeze soup?

Tags: freezing, soup

I am planning on making soup with my leftover turkey frame. I was just wondering if it is possible to freeze the soup and have it taste good when it is thawed. I am guessing it should be fine as long there aren't any noodles in the soup. Other than that the only ingredients called for are vegetables (celery, can of diced tomatoes, carrots, mushrooms) and spices.

What do you think?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Soup freezes great in my experience.  To freeze it for long term storage, you'll probably want it to be vacuum sealed.  In order to do this I freeze individual sized portions in Tupperware-style containers (make sure to leave enough room for expansion), and as soon as they're solid, vacuum seal those large "cubes".  They generally stack pretty nicely in our garage freezer.

In general soups should thaw and taste very good, some flavors even seem become stronger or seem to enhance and meld better with the freezing.  If you vacuum seal them as above you can throw them (still sealed) into a pot of boiling water for hot soup relatively fast!

As an aside, another great option with a leftover turkey frame would be to save it with previous odds and ends (carrot/celery ends, onion pieces, etc) in the freezer, and when you have enough make a simple stock.  You can then freeze the stock into cubes (in ice cube trays) for soup-making later, sauteeing veggies, in place of water for more flavorful rice, and a ton of other things.

Comment: +1 for stock-making.  While yes the soup will freeze fine, the stock makes for a useful flavour addition to lots of later cooking.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to mention leaving room for expansion while freezing.

Answer (score 8):

I usually freeze soup in ice cubes trays and when the cubes are frozen, I transfer them to a freezing bag.

Small soup cubes defrost faster than big soup blocks, so when I come back home late and tired from work, I can have a hot soup in a few minutes, just putting some cubes in a hot pan...

Comment: Good trick!

Answer (score 6):

I freeze soup all the time. The only issue I've ever had is that the texture of large pieces of vegetables can change slightly after they're frozen -- possibly because the ice crystals break cell walls. I've noticed this particularly with potatoes and carrots. But only large pieces seem to have this problem.

Comment: Indeed. The size of my pieces tends to depend on what I will be doing with the leftovers...

Answer (score 3):

We freeze soup all the time, either in plastic containers or in freezer bags. We haven't had any problems with noodles in frozen soups.

Answer (score 2):

That will freeze (and thaw) just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Soup usually freezes beautifully. Some veggies may suffer a slight texture change, if that is a problem, you can just freeze the meat and broth, and add fresh veggies when you thaw and reheat.

Comment: The texture of meat also changes - less of a problem if you use smaller pieces in general.